# username and email validation works but when I hit in submit button, it still proceeds

Tags: c#, submit, registration

i have these codes as my username and email validation if they are existing in the database or not. so far i am able to make them work(validations do appear) However, even though that for example username exists and i clicked on submit, still it pushes through? what am i missing here?

```
protected void txtUser_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text))
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserData where Username=@Username", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                lblusercheck.Text = "Username exists";
                lblusercheck.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                imgstatus.Visible = true;
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "Images1/work/NotAvailable.png";
            }
            else
            {
                lblusercheck.Text = "Username available!";
                lblusercheck.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
                imgstatus.Visible = true;
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "Images1/work/Available.png";
            }
            conn.Close();


        }
    }

    protected void txtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text))
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserData where Email=@Email", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                lblemailcheck.Text = "Email already used";
                lblemailcheck.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                ImageEmail.Visible = true;
                ImageEmail.ImageUrl = "Images1/work/NotAvailable.png";
            }
            else
            {
                lblemailcheck.Text = "Email Approved";
                lblemailcheck.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
                ImageEmail.Visible = true;
                ImageEmail.ImageUrl = "Images1/work/Available.png";
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

and here is my submit button code:

```
protected void btn_Registration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into UserData(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Password,CustomerType,DeliveryAddress,Zip,ContactNumber)values(@Username,@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@CustomerType,@DeliveryAddress,@Zip,@ContactNumber)";
            SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPW.Text));
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", txtAddress.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);

            scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Session["Contact"] = txtContact.Text;
            Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
            Session["DeliveryAddress"] = txtAddress.Text;
            label_register_success.Text = ("Registration Successful!");
            //Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, you should have both client and server side validation.

Comment: how will i know? @msmolcic please guide me im new to this. thank you